# Firebase get a value under unknown push key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get that value while I know nothing about the push key?

```
+users
  +9JZTuGUzc8bx7FLrwResWmp8L583 

     +anon:

     +email:

     +fid: <- i want to get this id without knowing push key (9JZTuGUzc8bx7FLrwResWmp8L583 )

     +username:
```

Currently, I am trying with a null response:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("anon").equalTo(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POST_USERNAME))
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Get user information
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                            fidanon = user.fid;}

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

                    });
```

Comment: please attach your complete db structure

Comment: And also attach the rule for your db screen, screenshot,

Comment: no problem thats all no rule problem

Comment: then attach your complete db structure please

Comment: this is complete structure

Comment: What's the value of your `getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POST_USERNAME)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("anon").equalTo(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POST_USERNAME));
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                        final String fid = dataSnapshot.child("fid").getValue().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), fid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Use this,will solve your problem.